# can't get the selected value of radio button in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form which has various input field with a common name(input array field). I tried to access the value of all elements once the form gets submitted. I able to access all the input field apart from the radio button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getValue(elem) {
    let val = $(elem).val();
    if (val === "video") {
      let other = $("#videoLink").val();
      return other;
    }
    if (val === "youtube") {
      let other = $("#youtubeLink").val();
      return other;
    }
  }

  $("#submit").on("click", function() {
    $("#form").trigger("submit");
  })

  $("#form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstNameValues = $("input[name='firstName[]']").map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    
    var lastNameValues = $("input[name='lastName[]']").map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    
    var linkValues = $("input[name='link[]']:checked").map(function() {
      return getValue(this)
    }).get();
  })
  
  $("#add-more").on("click", function() {
    $("#form > .container").clone().insertAfter("#form");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <form name="form" id="form" class="form" method="post">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <input type="text" name="firstName[]" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <input type="text" name="lastName[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <input type="radio" name="link[]" value="youtube">Youtube:<input type="text" id="youtubeLink" name="youtubeLink[]" placeholder="Youtube" />
        <input type="radio" name="link[]" value="video">Video<input type="text" id="videoLink" name="videoLink[]" placeholder="Video" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <button type="button" id="add-more">Add</button>
  <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try textContent instead of val()

Comment: The code seems to work fine in a snippet. If you select from the radio, then type in the input next to it, the `map()` call will put the values in to an array. Why do you believe there is an issue? How have you debugged this? There's no logging in the code.

Comment: Is the issue after you click [add]?  This line `$("#videoLink").val()` will only get the *first* videolink input - you need to add context, eg `$(elem).find("input").val()` will give you each input.

Comment: However, there's also an issue with your radio groups.  Radio buttons all work from the same name - so once you click [add] a few times, they all work as the same set of radio (can only select one radio from multiple containers, not 1 per container).  So two obvious issues for you.